# xmlhttp.open in page1 calls page2 result in ID of page1

Tags: javascript, asp.net

To avoid post back I use `xmlhttp.open`.

So far, I managed to display text on the bottom of page1 using the called page2

```
function showMada(str) 
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getmada.aspx?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How can I change the contents of a specific `textbox` and a `P` tag in page1?

Thanks

Comment: You do not have enough information in your question for us to answer. Please post how the page looks after the send. I assume you have an onreadystatechange handler that actually inserts the page?

Comment: Also it sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you exactly trying to solve with this?

Comment: It is a page that displays many things, one part of it is a text that if you click next button it will give next text without posting too many things

Comment: Please post more code. And also perhaps stay on one Q&A platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you must assign the id to the tag in which you want to change your text like

`<p id = "demo"></p>`

And then to specifically change the data add this in your AJAX function

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;`

Hope this might help you.

Comment: the added line document.get .... would be in page1 or 2?

Comment: Obviously,in page 1 as you are calling the page 2  by AJAX in page 1

Comment: it is giving (undefined) in the P tag on page 1 while still at the bottom of page 1 is displaying the text from page 2 so I replaced  this.responseText  by "xyz", then xyz is displayed ok in P tag - which means that   this.responseText   is not directing result of page 2 to the P tag ID on page 1

Comment: where did you added the answer above in your code?

Comment: after xmlhttp.open and xmlhttp.send

Comment: No,it should be in your AJAX function  ( xhttp.onreadystatechange  = function() { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {.... } }) where you can see dotted.

Comment: you are right  Kunal Raut  it needs a delay in order to execute document.getEle..... this is a good answer  thank you